How do I install a Supplementary Security Domain?
I'm currently researching OTA deployment procedures for the JavaCard, and during that research I tried creating an SSD. I tried doing it with GlobalPlatformPro, but I have not been able to yet. gp -domain <AID> only throws an error.
This stackoverflow thread kind of made me worried though:
What are the correct steps to have a supplementary security domain with DAP verification?
My card does not have any applet or package with the AID A0000001515350. But I want to be sure, am I able to implement one myself, or should I just buy a different card?
For context: I'm working with sysmoISIM SJA5. I tried to see what their specifications say about Security Domains, but I don't see a lot of information on that topic. If I need to buy a new card, then I would like to know what I should look out for in their specs.

If your card doesn't have a card manager at AID A0000001515350 then it likely uses A0000000030000 which was what Open/GlobalPlatform used. The RID (the first 5 bytes) of the AID however indicates VISA (i.e. the third registered organization), so they later changed it to an RID of GlobalPlatform itself.
